# Need help with a Linear Programming homework.

Tags: linear-programming

Please help with the problem:

> A polyhedron P in $R^n$ is given by the system of m linear
>   inequalities (of n variables). Furthermore, let P have k vertices
>   (that is, k vectors satisfying all m constraints at least for n of
>   which the equalities hold).
>
> a) If m = 7; n = 2, might k be equal to: 0; 1; 7; 8; 23?
>   b) If m = 6; n = 3, might k be equal to: 0; 1; 6; 8; 9; 21?
>   c) If m = 8; n = 7, might k be equal to: 0; 1; 2; 7; 8; 9; 10?
>   d) If m = n = 6, might k be equal to: 0; 1; 2; 3?
>   e) If m = 4; n = 5, might k be equal to: 0; 1; 2?
>   Give an example if the answer is "yes" and explain why not if it is "no".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know how to solve it correctly. But it seems like it's somehow related to [Euler characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic), which states that

$V-E+F = 2$, for any convex polyhedron, where

V - vertices, E - edges, F - faces of polyhedron.

We can assume that $E \leq m$ and $F \leq n$, therefore $E \leq m+n-2$.

So for every k you chould check the inequality $k\leq m+n-2$.

It looks like it's gonna work in many cases, if you have answers please compare them with this inequality.

Comment: @con thanks for the replay. I don't have the answers; but when we go over it in class, I will be sure to post them here.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense. Why would you assume that $E \leq m$ and $F \leq n$? (Counterexample: a cube is determined by 6 inequalities in 3 unknowns. Yet $E = 12 \not \leq 6$, and $F = 6 \not \leq 3$.)

Comment: Furthermore, you don't want a bound that "looks like it's gonna work in many cases", you want a bound that you can _prove_ will work in _all_ cases.